# UART TO RS-232 convension

Tags: pic, serial, uart

I am working on a project and I use several PIC18F26K83's for this project. For communication between PIC's I use UART. Now I also need to send data with RS232 to the user. As I have understood the main difference between UART and RS-232 is voltage levels. And with PIC I cannot supply proper voltage level that is required for RS232. Because of that UART to RS232 converter's look like a must. (i.e. MAX232) I have two questions.

1. Using UART to RS232 chips is the only option in this case? Are there any alternative ways?
2. I am planning to send UART data directly to the UART to RS232 converter chip. I do not know how they work, code wise do I need to change anything? Can I directly put UART tx data to the receive pin of these chips? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Using UART to RS232 chips is the only option in this case? Are
>   there any alternative ways?

Of course, you can implement a level converter using discrete hardware. For instance, [this site](http://picprojects.org.uk/projects/simpleSIO/ssio.htm) describes the following very simple circuit:

[image]

Please take care of the "operating notes".

> code wise do I need to change anything?

No.

> Can I directly put UART tx data to the receive pin of these chips?

Yes.

Comment: Remember that this driver, like most you can buy, inverts between UART and RS232.

Comment: Does that it does not invert RS232 to UART?

Comment: That circuit won't meet RS232 specifications.  It may often work, but only if connected to something that goes beyond specification.  Use a chip that does it right with charge pumps, or the old way with extra power supplies.